# Is a precedent of the Upper Tribunal binding on a county court?

Tags: court, appeal, precedent, tribunal

It is said to have the equivalent status of the High Court, so that would suggest yes. And yet, it is not a proper court, so to speak, so what is the status of its decisions on lower courts that are not tribunals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_Tribunal)

> The Upper Tribunal is a superior court of record, giving it equivalent status to the High Court and meaning that it can both set precedents and can enforce its decisions (and those of the First-tier Tribunal) without the need to ask the High Court or the Court of Session to intervene. It is also the first (and only) tribunal to have the power of judicial review.

Comment: It clearly can set precedents that are binding upon the FTT, but does that traverse the court/tribunal divide to bind the county courts?